# Displaying a single class as block instead of inline inside of a for sentence

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I am working on a site which changes languages depending on the language of the browser.

**Setting the language**

```
var language = navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language;
languageFirstTwo = language.substr(0,2); // To only keep the first 2 characters.
global = languageFirstTwo;
```

Most of the site then uses the *inline* layout mode as shown below.

**inline** layout

```
function setLanguage(language) {
    global = language;
    for (var i = 0; i < lngs.length; i++) {
        if (lngs[i].className.includes(language)) {
            lngs[i].style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            lngs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

I would somehow like to edit the above code, so that only the class `.small` uses the **block** layout style.

I was thinking something along these lines, but this obviously does not work...

```
function setLanguage(language) {
    global = language;
    var small = document.getElementsByClassName("small");
    for (var i = 0; i < lngs.length; i++) {
        if (lngs[i].className.includes(language)) {
            lngs[i].style.display = "inline";
            small.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            lngs[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `global = language` ?? btw?  I took it out.  language is passed into the function,  assuming `global` is a variable set on the window?   you can add that line back in if it is needed for some other part of the code, but it makes no sense to me lol

Also, the array `lngs` is not declared in this function so assuming it is scoped through a closure of some kind.  If this code is still not working for you,  you probably need to pass `lngs` into your function as well, or even better, don't even write a function for it as it is just one line of code.

**Calling your Function**

First things first...  (if `global` is an actual variable in scope and somewhere else in your code it needs that set, you will want to add that line back in but pretty sure that your assignment of `global` does nothing so i took it out)

```
setLanguage(navigator.languages[0] || navigator.language);
```

**Nested Ternary**
(so fresh and so clean clean)

```
const setLanguage = (language) => 
  for (var i = 0; i < lngs.length; i++) 
    lngs[i].style.display = lngs[i].className.includes(language.substr(0,2)) ? 
      (lngs[i].className.includes("small") ? 
        "block" : "inline") : "none";
```

Alternatively, you could use `.querySelectorAll()` if nested ternaries aren't your thing ...

**.querySelectorAll()**

```
const setLanguage = (language) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < lngs.length; i++) 
    lngs[i].style.display = lngs[i].className.includes(language.substr(0,2)) ?
      "inline" : "none";
  [].forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("."+language.substr(0,2)), 
    (ele) => ele.style.display = ele.className.includes("small") ?
      "block" : "inline";
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try tomorrow. I'm still not great at programing, so I try to keep things simple (I prefer more, longer code which I can understand "at a glance"). Could I ask you to extned your your code, so that it looks more similair to what i have so far. And yes, I'm not adding var/let/const because of scope. For some reason the code didn't work if I didn't add *global = language*. A bit tired sorry. Thank you again for the help.